# How can I manage document sizes in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

In inkscape, there are many predefined document size templates:

[image: Ctrl+Shift+D dialog - paper sizes]

Most of them are quite useless for me. However I'd like to add different ones. For example the horizontal A4 would be quite useful.

How can I manage the document size list so that it contains the sizes I want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open Inkscape.
- Setup the page the way you want it.
- Save it as an "Inkscape SVG" in the Inkscape templates folder for your user, with the name you'd like to see.
- Close and restart Inkscape.

On Windows this is located at `%appdata%\inkscape\templates`.
On Linux and Mac it's at `~/.config/inkscape`.

Once it's saved in there it will be added to the list for New documents for you user.

For example, I made an A4 in landscape, and saved it with the name `A4_Land.vsg`:

[image]

To remove the existing ones, or to add a custom document templates for all users on the machine to use, you'll need administrator access to the machine.

Head to the Inkscape program folder (i.e. on Windows: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\share\templates`) and delete the ones you don't want, and/or save the new ones you want available to all users.

Comment: I assume the other templates are built-in the code then? Doesn't that sound unlikely...?

Comment: I found them.. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

today I had the same question and this answer at least for current version 1.2 is not what I needed. Page sizes are not the same as templates.

So I did some more research and out of curiosity I dig in .config/inkscape folder and found a pages.csv with all documents dimensions. Adding a few media sizes for social networks posts, save, reload inkscape and it work nicely.